# PostgreSQL query for elapsed interval

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to query PostgreSQL database for rows where interval has elapsed from the last run. Main columns for this purpose are `processed_at` as `timestamptz` and `frequency` (in minutes) as `integer`.

I am failing with operators, since not many of them can operate together timestamp & integer.

Can someone please propose a query that would solve this? Thank you very much for help

Comment: What is the meaning of those columns that you mentioned?

Comment: `select now() - (10::varchar || ' min')::interval; 2021-10-15 08:35:07.988718-07`, where you would substitute `frequency` for fixed value in the example.

Comment: @luckongas Well, as I have written above, `processed_at` is a timestamp of the last run of a program/process and `frequency` is an interval in minutes, in which program should run. So say, I will query a database every minute, to see which programs are eligible to run again

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Would you be so kind and explain the query, please?

Comment: See my answer for further explanation.

Comment: See my UPDATE to answer for a shorter way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here [Date/time operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

> timestamp + interval → timestamp

> Add an interval to a timestamp

> timestamp '2001-09-28 01:00' + interval '23 hours' → 2001-09-29 00:00:00

```
select now() + (10::varchar || ' min')::interval;
           ?column?            
-------------------------------
 2021-10-15 09:05:37.927163-07


--Or in your case. If I'm following you are adding the interval.

select processed_at + (frequency::varchar || ' min')::interval;
```

The query takes the integer value of minutes and converts it to an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) of minutes that can be added to the timestamp.

Further explanation, `||` is the Postgres concatenation operator and `::varchar`, `::interval` are casting shorthand.

**UPDATE**

I keep forgetting about the `make_*()` functions for date/time/interval

```
--A shorter version

select processed_at + make_interval(mins => frequency);
```

Saves all the casting.

Comment: It will likely be more efficient to go the other direction - subtract the interval from now and then query for `<=` that smaller timestamp. Adding would likely preclude index usage.